# Microsoft Word Citation Error - Showing the Article Title

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, bibliography, citations

I encounter this problem when I have at least two paper references written by the same person. I use APA format, and when you cite a paper in the document, the format should go: (Lastname, Year).

There is no problem until I add the second paper from a person whose first paper I have used in the document. When that happened, their format went: (Lastname, Title, Year). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMCMJ.png) I attach the screenshot as well.

I've searched in Office Forum with terms "Word citation error" or "Two references from the same author", but yielded no result. I am using Microsoft 365. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What is the error?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thanks, the error is that when you have one same author with two different papers to cite, the citation will show the title (Lastname, Title, Year), not the normal ones (Lastname, Year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the title manually. Right-click on the citation, select Edit Citation.

[image: IMG:]

On the Edit Citation window, on the Suppress section, select Title, then click OK.

[image: IMG:]